Contact form ticket to appeal suspension was closed without any response by Stack Exchange
Stack Overflow moderators banned me for a year. I appealed the account suspension. The reply to my appeal makes no sense:

RE: 126302 - Appeal of temporary account suspension
We've closed this ticket because it appears the issue was resolved. Please let us know if you have any questions or continue to have issues. Since this ticket is now closed, it will no longer be monitored and cannot be re-opened. If you still have any issues, please feel free to create a new ticket.
Thanks!
Stack Overflow & Stack Exchange Support Team
126302

FYI
For the curious, this is what Stack Overflow moderators sent me after the ban Banned from Stack Overflow #22.
I don't see any content warranting a ban.  I have a thick skin and it's basically impossible for me to be offended by some comments on the Internet.
The only reasoning the SO mod-squad gave for banning me is solely based on my comments on a Stack Exchange Web site.
So, to get rid of the possibility of somebody claiming my comments hurt their feelings, or they feel offended by my comments, or they blame me for their emotions and individual sensitivities getting triggered by the content of my comments, or something of the sort, I am not going to post any comments on Stack Exchange Web sites anymore. After all, Stack Exchange Web sites are allegedly for questions and answers anyway. The question should contain all relevant details, and so should the answer.
If/when this ban is lifted or expires I might post questions or answers on Stack Exchange Web sites. That's it.
The reply to my account suspension appeal by Stack Exchange still doesn't makes any sense given the context.
For completeness, this is my account suspension appeal:

I'm trying to figure out why my account was suspended. The comments SO
mod-squad used for their collective decision to suspend my account
don't make sense to me.
I simply shared my opinion of matters, without rancor or "disrespect".
There are no lies or "disrespect" in my comments.

We can use fetch() for file: protocol in some cases. Downvoting my answer won't change that fact.

I deleted my Meta question. Nobody actually answered the question. Instead people wanted to engage me in comments. They offered their
opinion. I offered mines. I don't see the other people got banned for
offering their opinions.

Voting is literally a social and political act. That's a fact.


You omitted including comments thnaking [sic] me for my attention to detail
and helping them on SO.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78216230

Thanks to "guest271314" for suggesting I look into MediaSource.

I have no rancor in my heart for the mod-squad of SO users. I have no
plans on asking any more questions on Meta.
So I'm still wondering what is the basis of my account suspension . I
don't think my truthful comments and my opinion of voting being a
social, political activity warrants my account being suspended.
I look forward to StackOverflow [sic] moderator team - excluding the people
who voted to suspend my account as that would be a conflict of
interest - explaining exactly how my comments above warrant account
suspension.
If the only issue is me making comments on SO, I can simply not
comment on SO whatsoever, just answer questions or ask question.
My account suspension should be immediately lifted in any case.
Thanks.


I am not familiar with their ticketing system, but that looks like the sort of email that gets generated when somebody closes the ticket without doing anything else. If that was an intentional choice on their part, then one possible interpretation would be "Your appeal is denied, and we have no further comment on it." But I would prefer for them to say that explicitly.

A ticket has been raised to make the CM team aware of this post. Note that it may take a while before anyone has a chance to look at it.

Separately, let's maybe stop speculating about why the user was suspended.  That's not really relevant to the issue raised here, which is about the unclear response to the appeal, rather than the suspension itself.

Judging from the staff-generated letter you link to, it seems there may be little more to say on the subject. To me, it makes perfect sense. You say it makes no sense to you and you seek to blame the sensitivity of others for being offended, but... you show no contrition, remorse or insight into your behaviour or the consequences. Do you show any intent to change?  Little more to say.

SO mods aren't lifting the ban, CM team has closed the appeal ticket with no additional action, and nobody here has any further capability (or based on the apparent attitude in this post, incentive) to do anything about. So, what, exactly, besides a rant and a threat to never come back, are you expecting to achieve here? Flagged as off-topic, not seeking input, because it just doesn't and can't.

@RyanM FYI, the author of the question edited in a link to the mod message they were sent, and the email they sent to SE. In other words, they've made the details public.

The response you got appears to be automated, and I see it as "We have no reason to interfere, or lift the suspension", though I do agree it might have been better to get such response from actual CM. However I also trust the CM team enough to believe they did check the facts, the mod actions, and your actions, and came to the conclusion not to change the mod team decision. I can't help or say much more except perhaps rephrase @W.O. words: you did something wrong, and the first step is realizing that, and acting towards changing that, if possible, and for that you have almost one year.

Also, I'm not sure what you expect to get by posting here. Seeing people who yell "Yes! You're correct!"? Or something more? Because there might be people who agree with you and would like to see your suspension lifted, however it's not really relevant for you, as the people who can do that already saw everything, reviewed it, and reached their own conclusion.

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda They seem to ask for clearer feedback, and not just a boilerplate response. Which seems to be a reasonable request. That the answer is "you won't get it" also seems perfectly reasonable, and I fully agree with your second to last comment: that the mod teams probably have sufficient reason not to engage any longer. To the OP: you show on what basis you have been suspended again; this implies you have behaved worse in the past, and showed no signs of change this time around. Nevertheless, the details are irrelevant to your request for clarification.

@Joachim regarding "worse in the past" - doesn't have to be worse, might as well be just the same. Anyway I do agree the question here can stay, didn't vote to close and won't vote to delete if closed, but just... can't see a way the OP will get the reply they want.

@W.O. Judging from other entries in the "issues" for the repository that OP linked (which detail other cases in which the OP was banned from other places), this is someone who sincerely believes things such as "there is no such thing as 'tone' on the Internet". So the apparent lack of "contrition, remorse or insight" is hardly mysterious.

I've found the ticket ID 126302 in our system and I'm happy to clarify what happened here.
We received your appeal on March 31st. On April 1st it got forwarded to the Trust and Safety team (and you received an automated email saying so). It seems, however, you may have missed our response, so I'm going to paste it here (with some light editing for privacy). The following was sent to you on Tuesday, April 9th:

Hello guest271314,
Thank you for contacting us. I see you have been suspended from Stack Overflow to cool off based on recent interactions on the site. I have looked into your situation and are happy to address your concerns. In your correspondence you mentioned you do not believe your actions warrant a suspension. I have investigated this situation fully and hope I can provide some clarity and guidance moving forward.
During my investigation I saw a long history of moderators reaching out to give you warnings about your behavior. Moderators have given you specific instances which I can affirm are violations of our Code of Conduct.  Comments such as:
"[redacted]"
Along with a history of [redacted] cross a line. As such, I believe that moderator actions in this situation were reasonable and have decided to uphold the suspension. If there is anything else we can help with please do not hesitate to contact us.
Regards,
[CM Name] - Stack Exchange Trust & Safety Team

on Friday, April 12th, because there was no response to the ticket, it got automatically closed - which is when you received the automated message pasted in your question informing that it was closed.

I am glad that you handled the appeal relatively quickly, in under 1.5 weeks. In the past, this used to take many months.

So perhaps change the automated close message to something like "We've closed this ticket because it appears the issue was resolved and you did not respond to our previous message", to prevent such confusion as in this case, making it clear a previous message has been sent?
